# Is it possible to run a Python app on a WordPress site?

Tags: python, wordpress

I have an idea for a web app and plan to learn Python as I go (right now I know html/css, some javascript, some php and sql). The app would be able to manipulate and analyze audio files, among other things.

Ideally, I'd like to make the app available through my wordpress site so that I can take advantage of WordPress's login management and the plugin s2member's subscription management and content restriction capabilities.

Is that possible? Would it even make sense?

If not, is there a better alternative to automate all of that (the subscription management, logins, payment processing, content restriction, etc) without having to code it myself?

Comment: wordpress is php, so probably... no, there isn't. you could TALK to wordpress via http or whatever. but directly invoking wordpress functions from python? not possible.

Comment: There are libraries like python-wordpress-rpc (name from memory; google it to find the real name…) that try to make the clean solution (a Python web service that talks to a Wordpress web service) as seamless as possible. But you'd still need to do the work to write the "front end" side of your Python service, including delegating authentication and user management.

Comment: Does the Wordpress site already exist? Otherwise this is definitely a bad X-Y problem. If it doesn't need to integrate with existing WP site, I'd suggest Google App Engine (GAE).

Comment: @Ollie Ford - The WP site is in the early stages so it's not a problem to change. I'm looking into GAE - sounds pretty enticing but it's not clear - does it do the subscription management, login management and all that other stuff WP or WP plugins do?

Comment: Login (via Google accounts, or otherwise) yes. There's no centralised 'plugin store' similar to WP, but you can search around and find something in Python that needn't be intended for use on GAE.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I suggest you develop a REST API in Python and extend your Wordpress site to consume that API.

For the Python side, you could go with Flask and use [Flask-RESTful](https://flask-restful.readthedocs.org).

For the Wordpress side, have a look at [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/28229/consuming-an-external-api-in-wordpress).

Answer (score 10):

Sure, if you meet a couple of conditions:

- The server your wordpress site is on also has python
- And you have the ability run arbitrary python scripts on said server.

Here's a (very contrived) example of how to do it from a plugin:

call-python.php (plugin file):

```
<php
/*
Plugin name: Call Python
Author:..
....
*/

$pyScript = "/path/to/app.py";

exec("/usr/bin/python $pyScript", $output);
var_dump($output);
```

And the python script app.py:

```
print("Hello, World")
```

And that's it! That will dump Hello, world to the body. Obviously you'll need a bit more for a more complicated python app, but it will work.

Like others are saying, there may be better "more correct" ways of doing it. But if your end goal is to run a python app from WordPress it's possible.